# sort command doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, function

It seems that sort command doesn't work properly for the following sample text:

```
    a-band  1
    a-band  1
    a-banda 1
    abandoned-as    1
    abandoned-his   1
    abandoned-holmes        1
    abandons-himself        1
    a-bank  1
    a-barmaid       1
    a-barred
```

I tried using "sort -k1,1" and "sort -k1" and any other combination, but I'm still getting the above result which is obviously not correct! any idea?

Comment: It's not "obviously not correct."  What exactly do you think is wrong?  It looks to me like it's ignoring the hyphens, but you'd prefer that it take the hyphens into account, maybe?

Answer (score 6):

You probably want a non-locale-aware sort:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort file.txt
```

That may affect the way non-roman characters are sorted, but it will avoid issues with dashes and whitespace, which many default European locales ignore for collation purposes.

Comment: Came to post this.  Without this, the dash is essentially ignored and the sorting in the question correct.